# Visual studio 2022 demanding dependencies of libary

Tags: c++, static-libraries, visual-studio-2022, static-linking

So I will start from the beginning, I wrote an application and then transformed it to a static libary to use its classes in an another application that I am writing, **this libary is building just fine** and giving me a .lib file that I can use, but it has its own dependencies (my libary) like glfw, vulkan and glm. **I put my libary in the same solution of the application that I am writing and referenced it by right clicking and adding it as reference, adding its source folder as include directories.** But when I try to build my application It gives me **errors like: "cannot open source file GLFW/glfw3.h" witch is an include in my libary files and not a dependency for my application.**
Like I said i still can build my libary, so I am linking its own libaries just fine. Can you help me?

Comment: Yes, add the location of `GLFW/glfw3.h` to your include directories when building your application.

Comment: And BTW adding a reference to the library to your application is **not** the correct way to build with a library.

Comment: @john ah really I was following chernos (a youtuber who builds game engines) tutorial to link my libary, I didnt know that thats the first time I am working with a custom libary

Comment: @john should I link glfw and other libaries to my application too?

Comment: Your basic mistake seems to be assuming that libraries are self contained. So all you need to do is include a reference to the library when building an application that uses the library. That is not correct. If your library has a header file that includes a third party header file, then you need to add the location of that third party header file when you build your application. And the same is true when you link your application, you will need to add your library and the third party library.

Comment: Yes you should.

Comment: @john Yes I was thinking like that, but no tutorial on internet shows how to create libaries with dependenies of its own.. So I have another question if I dont bother you too much; All the file paths on my libary now seraching the file inside my application solution, like my shader files and stuff, I dont want to add my shaders to my application folder and keep them inside my libary, why it is searching it inside the application?

Comment: I expect that you are using relative file paths for your shaders etc. Relative paths are resolved against the *current working directory* when the code is run, not when it is built. So that would be why they are being looked for in the application folder. There are a few solutions for this issue 1) use absolute paths 2) change the current working directory when your library code is executing 3) use resources, with resources your shaders are physically located in the library instead of being located on the file system. Using resources typically involves some support from the platform.

Comment: I don't know enough about GLFW to know if it supports a resource concept.

Answer (score 0):

Your library is not self-contained, that is, you were to include a file relative to the library path, but this relative path is being searched for in the application path at runtime. A solution would be to create a folder in your application for your library, create a GLFW folder inside that and copy the glfw3.h file into the GLFW folder. That would save you from a lot of headaches.